# MaterializeCSS Tabs instance return undefined

Tags: javascript, materialize

I try do tabs with steps and use for that some trigger button.

But my tab instance return undefined for that i cant use all of methods

```
   var TabInstance = M.Tabs.getInstance(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs'));
   var nextStep = document.querySelectorAll('.next-step'), nS;

   for (nS = 0; nS < nextStep.length; ++nS) {
      nextStep[nS].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        alert(TabInstance) // undefined

        var 
        where = this.getAttribute("href"),
        newWhereWithoutHash = where.replace('#', '');

        TabInstance.select(newWhereWithoutHash); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined
       });
   }
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having a similar issue.

Comment: @Chiperific Yes, getInstance() method allow just one element, you can give ID or specfic class then call this method.